# Gerar números aleatórios sem repetir o número gerado anteriormente

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um programa que simule o jogo "Porta da Esperança" do Silvio Santos no Pyton e preciso que o programa gere um número aleatório, excluindo o número gerado anteriormente. Fiz dessa forma:

```
premio = rd.randint(1,3)

p = int(premio)

print(p)

w = rd.sample(range(1,3), p)

print(w)
```

Mas aparece um aviso dizendo que o sample é maior que a população. Não sei como fazer de outro jeito!

P.s.: pra quem quiser ajudar no programa como um todo, aqui está a questão:

> Faça um programa que simule o comportamento do Sílvio Santos. Seu
>   programa deve:
>
> 1. escolher aleatóriamente uma das três portas e colocar o prêmio
>      atrás dela (não informe o usuário onde está o prêmio);
> 2. pedir
>      ao usuário que ele escolha uma das três portas;
>          abrir uma porta que não tenha o prêmio e que o usuário não tenha escolhido (se houver mais de uma escolha para a porta a ser
>      aberta,
>      seu programa deve abrir qualquer uma delas com igual probabilidade);
> 3. mostrar ao usuário qual porta foi aberta;
> 4. perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja manter sua escolha inicial ou se ele deseja trocar de porta;
> 5. mostrar ao usuário se ele ganhou ou não o prêmio.

Comment: Faça um Fisher-Yates: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fisher+yates

Comment: Esse problema deve estar ocorrendo porque o 'p' deve ter recebido valor 3, porém o range(1,3) gera uma lista de 2 números: [1, 2]. O correto seria range(1,4)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro faça uma lista de portas. Vamos supor que estamos trabalhando com 10 portas.

```
*l, = range(1,11)
```

irá gerar:

```
>>l
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Agora vamos excluir da lista um número aleatório. Basta embaralhar os itens e retirar o último. Ele será o prêmio.

```
import random
random.shuffle(l)
premio = l.pop()
```

Peça para o usuário escolher uma porta.

```
user = input('Escolha uma porta de um a dez')
```

Retire a porta que o usuário escolheu da lista.

```
try:
    l.remove(int(user))
except:
    pass
```

Usamos try/except para evitar um **ValueError** caso ele escolha a porta com o prêmio ( que não está mais na lista e, portanto, não pode ser retirada ).

Já tiramos da lista a porta com o prêmio e a porta que o usuário escolheu. Basta embaralhar de novo e tirar a última: essa porta não tem o prêmio, nem foi escolhida pelo usuário.

```
random.shuffle(l)
print('A porta ' + str(l.pop()) + ' foi aberta')
```

O resto do programa é trivial.

Basta comparar a nova porta escolhida, int(new) obtido a partir de new = input(),  ou a porta mantida, int(user) , com a porta armazenada na variável premio.

Answer (score -1):

Basta gerar um numero e adicioná-lo a um array, depois quando for gerar um novo numero faça um foreach ou algo do género para passar por todas as posições do array verificando se alguma é igual ao novo numero gerado. Se for, gera um novo numero e a variável de incremento a 0 se não houver nenhum igual adiciona na ultima posição preenchida + 1

Comment: João, muitas vezes não conseguimos ter noção do grau de aprendizado da pessoas, apenas descrever a lógica não é uma boa resposta. Tente responder através de exemplos práticos para que qualquer pessoa (ou quase) possa entender a resposta.